# Django serializer - Aggregate a function

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Goal: Get the total of number of days for a trip

Each trip can have multiple legs of varying duration. I have calculated the duration of each leg using a function. I now need to calculate the total sum of all these legs for any given trip.

Models

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)

 
class Leg(models.Model):
    trip_name = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    depature_date = models.DateField()
    arrival_date = models.DateField()
  
    def total_days(self):
      return ((self.arrival_date - self.depature_date).days) + 1
```

Serializers

```
class Trip_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_no_of_days = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Trip 
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'total_no_of_days']

    def get_total_no_of_days(self, instance):
        return Leg.objects.filter(trip_name=instance.id).aggregate(Sum('total_days'))



class Leg_Full_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Leg
        fields = [ 'id', 'trip_name', 'depature_date', 'arrival_date' , 'total_days' ]
```

The issue I am having is I don't know how to use the total_days function in the Trip Serializer.

**Edit**

Adding view that calls the Serializer

```
class Trip_List (ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = Trip_Serializer

    def get_queryset(self):
      return Trip.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by("-id")
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with endpoint as well where you call the serializer

Answer (score 1):

The serializer field argument [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) states that you can absolutely serialize the result of a method in a serializer.

Since your method and serializer field have the same name I'm not sure if you'll actually need to define a `source` explicitly.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly shows the example better. Note that you probably need to specify that it's a read-only field.

```py
total_days = serializers.IntegerField(source="total_days", read_only=True)
```

Comment: you could use the serializers.ReadOnlyField as well

Answer (score 0):

You should use [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) query expression like this:

```
def get_total_no_of_days(self, instance):
   from django.db.models import F

   date_diff = F('arrival_date'), F('depature_date')
   legs = Leg.objects.filter(trip_name=instance.id).annotate(diff=date_diff)
   return sum([leg.diff.days + 1 for leg in legs])
```

If you are using MySQL database there is a function known as [DATEDIFF](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-mysql/) which does exactly what you are trying to do. To call this database function in ORM you can use [Func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) like this:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, DateField, ExpressionWrapper

date_diff = Func(F('arrival_date'), F('depature_date'), function="DATEDIFF")
days_inclusive = ExpressionWrapper(date_diff + 1, output_field=DateField())
legs = Leg.objects.filter(trip_name=instance.id).annotate(
          total_no_of_days=days_inclusive
       )

return legs.aggregate(Sum('total_no_of_days')).get('total_no_of_days__sum')
```

If you are using Postgres you check [this](https://www.commandprompt.com/education/postgresql-datediff-datetime-difference-in-years-months-etc/#:%7E:text=The%20DATE_PART()%20function%20is,between%20the%20given%20DateTime%20values.)

I would suggest if possible not to do query in serializer as it will impact performance better would be to do this in a view where you are calling the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call it in the serializer as follows:

```
class Trip_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_no_of_days = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Trip 
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'total_no_of_days']

    def get_total_no_of_days(self, instance):
        return instance.total_days()
```

I hope this helps you out

Comment: on attempting this I get this error " 'Trip' object has no attribute 'total_days'"